# Unexpected elseif

Tags: php, html, if-statement

```
if ($postcode > 6999 && $postcode < 8000); 
{
    echo "Tasmania";
    $postage_cost = "$22.50"; 
}   
elseif ($postcode > 5999); 
{
    echo "Western Australia";
    $postage_cost "$27.50";
}
elseif ($postcode > 4999); 
{
    echo "Southern Australia";
    $postage_cost "$15.00";
}
```

This is only a snippet;

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in C:\wamp\www\projects\output.php on line 29

I assume the unexpected would go to all of the elseif's

Comment: Remove the semi-colons after your `if` condition `elseif ($postcode > 5999);`

Comment: Does your code writing in `PHP`? Syntax are totally wrong. [Study first](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of problems in your code.

First - do not use `;` after IF/ElSEIF statement. It should be like

```
if ($postcode > 6999 && $postcode < 8000) {
    echo "Tasmania";
    $postage_cost = "$22.50"; 
} elseif ($postcode > 5999) {...
```

Why? Because semicolon is used to end a statement. So putting it right after your IF/ELSE/ELSEIF statement just makes it empty. Writing `;` after IF would be same as writing (except that you can assign the result to variable):

```
$foo = ($postcode > 6999 && $postcode < 8000); //$foo would be true or false
```

Second - some assignment operators are missing:

```
$postage_cost = "$27.50"; // Note the =
```

Fix these and you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

You have put the semicolon to every if else condition remove `;` Also you have not put `=` in some line so add that. You can try the following code

```
if ($postcode > 6999 && $postcode < 8000) {
    echo "Tasmania";
    $postage_cost = "$22.50"; 
    }   
    elseif ($postcode > 5999) {
    echo "Western Australia";
    $postage_cost = "$27.50";
    }
    elseif ($postcode > 4999) {
    echo "Southern Australia";
    $postage_cost = "$15.00";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there mustn't be semi-colons after your if-conditions. remove them and it will work:

```
if ($postcode > 6999 && $postcode < 8000) {
  echo "Tasmania";
  $postage_cost = "$22.50"; 
} elseif ($postcode > 5999) {
  echo "Western Australia";
  $postage_cost = "$27.50";
} elseif ($postcode > 4999) {
  echo "Southern Australia";
  $postage_cost = "$15.00";
}
```

Comment: Equals missing $postage_cost = "$15.00";

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (($postcode > 6999) && ($postcode < 8000)) 
{
    echo "Tasmania";
    $postage_cost = '$22.50'; 
}   
elseif ($postcode > 5999) 
{
    echo "Western Australia";
    $postage_cost='$27.50';
}
elseif ($postcode > 4999) 
{
    echo "Southern Australia";
    $postage_cost='$15.00';
}
```

Comment: Equals missing $postage_cost = "$15.00";

Comment: Main thing is that if $postage_cost value show in other area then $postage_cost='$15.00' is better.  But in this question main issue if elseif problem...

Comment: That's fine. But you should point out all the errors for the question. Your answer should not be in partially its guides the user clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `semicolon` from **if** and **elseif** statement

so code look like this

```
if ($postcode > 6999 && $postcode < 8000) {
echo "Tasmania";
$postage_cost = "$22.50"; 
}   
elseif ($postcode > 5999) {
echo "Western Australia";
$postage_cost = "$27.50";
}
elseif ($postcode > 4999) {
echo "Southern Australia";
$postage_cost = "$15.00";
}
```